# VS2017 intellisense for javascript properties added dynamicly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

after declaring a new javascript of object i have no problem of getting intellisense of the object and the properties that were included during declaration. I cannot find a solution for the properties declared afterwards to the object.

here is an example :

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi, what's your file type and solution type? I tried to test your code in a js file under the web application solution, it works fine like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmEz41Yfj8du0jHOp

Comment: Hello, it is javascript as yours. But it is not recognized as you can see in your picture (missing the wrench icon). That is not a problem when working in the same file, but when try to import intellisense of your object then it is. I tried to keep simple so i skipped that part from my question.

Comment: It seems by design, I got the same result as yours if I tried to use this object in another *.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same result if I use it in another js file directly.

But like this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense

Because JavaScript and TypeScript are now based on the same language service, they are able to interact in a richer way. For example, JavaScript IntelliSense can be provided for values declared in a .d.ts file (see TypeScript documentation), and types such as interfaces and classes declared in TypeScript are available for use as types in JsDoc comments.

So you could declare the value in the .d.s file, and then you could find all them in the js file's intellisense.

[image]

Update(Add the .d.s file):

declare interface P {

```
property2: string;

property1: string;

age: number;

address: {

    stree: string;
    zip: number;

}}
```

Comment: can you add an example of the d.ts to make the answer more completed?

Comment: @vfle,Just add a simple sample in my reply.